# whats wrong with this code?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer

I am reading contents from files of a directory. I have to segregate the files according to their names and then read their contents. When I run the code simply without reading the contents, all the files are being listed of a particular file name, but when I try to read the contents, it reads contents from only few files, in fact just 10 of them. But the directory has about 1000 files of a particular name. I am posting the code here.

```
for (i = 0; i <= filenames.length; i++) {
    read = new FileReader("trainfiles/"+filenames[i]);          
    br = new BufferedReader(read);

    if (filenames[i].matches(".*ham.*")) {
        System.out.println("ham:" + filenames[i]);
        while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(lines);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me where am i doing wrong!?
thanks

**EDIT #1** I did some modifications which I have been told here, but the problem still persists, here is the code.

```
for(i=0;i<=filenames.length;i++){
            read = new FileReader("trainfiles/"+filenames[i]);

            br = new BufferedReader(read);

            if(filenames[i].matches(".*ham.*")){
                System.out.println("ham:"+filenames[i]);

                        while((lines = br.readLine())!= null){
                            st = new StringTokenizer(lines);
                            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
                            }

                        }

            }
            br.close();
            read.close();




                        }
```

**EDIT #2** Now the code looks like this, but again...its not giving me the result I want.

```
for (i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
               try {


                if (filenames[i].matches(".*ham.*")) {
                     read = new FileReader("trainfiles/"+filenames[i]);          
                        br = new BufferedReader(read);
                    System.out.println("ham:" + filenames[i]);
                    while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        st = new StringTokenizer(lines);
                        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
                        }
                    }
                }
               } finally {

                read.close();
                br.close();
               }
            }
```

Comment: no there are some files whose name are spam.txt, i am just looking for the words ham and spam and reading there contents.. there are in total 2450 files..

Comment: Are you sure all of the files are being read? Try printing the file names out prior to the loop.

Comment: Yes it is printing all the files when I simply print it.. but when I write the code to read it..it fails to give the exact output.

Comment: What output *does* it give? Are the files listed correctly while not listing all the contents or does the program just abruptly terminate, etc? These simple differences will isolate the problem.

Comment: @pst no it is listing all the files I want when I simply not using bufferedreader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would re-write your code like this, and see what output you get:

```
for (filename : filenames) {
   if (filename.matches(".*ham.*")) {
      System.out.println("ham:" + filename);

      // reset these to null (where are they declared?)
      read = null;   
      br = null;   
      try {
         read = new FileReader("trainfiles/"+filename);          
         br = new BufferedReader(read);

         while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(lines);
            // st = new StringTokenizer(lines);
            // while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            //    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            // }
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         if (br != null) br.close();
         if (read != null) read.close();
      }
   } 
}
```

Some general comments on your original code:

1. Only use a `for` loop if you actually need the array index. Prefer a for-each loop (i.e. `for (filename : filenames) ...`).
2. Declare variables in the narrowest scope possible.  In this case, you should declare your `read` and `br` variables where I initialize them to `null`.
3. Never open a file unless you're going to use it.  Here, that means opening it *inside* the conditional block.
4. Since opening a file can throw an exception, `br` may not get initialized, in which case you can't `close` it. You need to check for `null` first.

Comment: well...I just copy pasted the program in a notepad and saved it as a java file and tested it in command prompt. And now I am atleast getting different filenames which was not shown in ecplise. I doubt that it is the limitation of console in eclipse, which cannot show large output. Even command prompt is doing the same. Is there any way to take the output of command prompt in a file?!!!!

Comment: on most OSes there's some way to redirect into a file: e.g. `java arg1 arg2 etc >someFile`.

Comment: @aaron Yes, it is taking all the files now. It was the limitation of eclipse console, and yes, it was my mistake to that i didnt close the readers. THANKS A TON GUYS...

Comment: @mad_programmer I added some comments on your original code that will hopefully help you avoid some issues in the future.

Comment: yup...thats a cool syntax. And I am now gonna try it for spam files too...thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You should close your `FileReader` object `read` as well.

Unless this is homework, I would also suggest you take a look at [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

**EDIT #1:** I would suggest doing both close operations in a finally block.

**EDIT #2:** Did you try this?

```
for (i = 0; i <= filenames.length; i++) {
   try {
    read = new FileReader("trainfiles/"+filenames[i]);          
    br = new BufferedReader(read);

    if (filenames[i].matches(".*ham.*")) {
        System.out.println("ham:" + filenames[i]);
        while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(lines);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            }
        }
    }
   } finally {
    br.close();
    read.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: +1: `br` should also be closed. Currently, it is only closed if the file name matches that pattern.

Comment: I did it, but then also its the same problem. I am not able to read the whole files whose name has ham in it.

Comment: I put the close methods for both filereader and bufferedreader outside the condition. The problem still persists..

Comment: @mad_programmer: As I mentioned in the other answer's comments, please provide your modified code. You are free to edit your question. I recommend you keep the original code and simply append on your modified code so we can see how it is progressing.

Comment: Yes, I tried finally, but still its not working with me. I am using eclipse. and I am also printing the file name which is being read. so thats why i can say that it is not taking all files which has ham in its filename.

Comment: Actually, no--`BufferedReader.close()` closes its underlying reader.

Comment: @Michael - thanks, didn't know that. Though, it's not a bad practice to get into IMHO. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use `i<filenames.length`. Second, `matches` expects a regular expression, not `*`-globs. The expression you used is a valid regular expression for `[something]ham[something]` - is that what you meant?

I don't think you need to close the Filereader - I think BR's `close` propagates up. But that's worth checking. **EDIT** as was mentioned, you need to always close the file, outside the if.

Comment: ok i removed <= to < filenames.length, but matches is something which is helping me out to segregate the file, my file has names such as ham12.txt or ham2030.txt and there are other files with names such as spam10.txt etc. So, that matches just search for that text in filename and segregates it.

Comment: Understood. But when I started, I tried to use shell-style filename globbing, and likely would've tried that pattern to match [something].ham.[something], with the dots. Just confirming that you understood it was a RE.

Comment: Or, better yet, only open the file _inside_ the `if`. Opening/closing a file is really expensive compared to checking a regex.

Answer (score 1):

1000+ files are a lot of files to read. If it can't read a file it should throw an exception (IOException to be specific). Maybe print the exception message in the catch block and paste it here.

I don't know the StringTokenizer class but does the code give errors when you just print the line without the StringTokenizer?

An other option is to use threads. You have the array of files and then you start some threads who reads a file (producer/consumer problem).

By the way, you can filter files with the class FileFilter.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29

Comment: actually i am building a spam filter for my assignment. So, I need to load the content of the file with ham and spam in a separate hashtable. I need StringTokenizer for that.